# Php Array to xml gives wrong output child -> parent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, simplexml

Hello i have mysql to array to xml codes and my codes giving wrong xml output normally must be parent child my array gives child parent :) my codes  here please help me.

```
function packages($limit,$type){
        $ret_array = array();
        $sql = "select ID,packageName,servicer,products,clients 
                from Packages order by ID asc limit $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            $obj['ID'] = $data->ID;
            $obj['packageName'] = $data->packageName;
            $obj['servicer'] = $data->servicer;
            $obj['products'] = $data->products;
            $obj['clients'] = $data->clients;

            $ret_array[] = $obj;
        }   


        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        array_walk_recursive($ret_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
        print $xml->asXML();


        return $ret_array;
    }
```

And gives output

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root><1>ID</1><Free>packageName</Free><1>servicer</1><3>products</3><10>clients</10><2>ID</2><Basic>packageName</Basic><3>servicer</3><25>products</25><50>clients</50><3>ID</3><Advanced>packageName</Advanced><5>servicer</5><50>products</50><100>clients</100><4>ID</4><Premium>packageName</Premium><10>servicer</10><100>products</100><250>clients</250></root>
```

and i want like this ;

```
  **output gives example <Free>packageName i want <packageName>Free**
```

thanks

Comment: What is `value` and what is `key` in your xml?

Comment: @u_mulder im new in php see output gives example <Free>packageName i want <packageName>Free  my codes top ty

Comment: Please add an example of expected output vs the output you got.

Comment: @k0pernikus i added output top side

Comment: FYI: [mysql_fetch_object](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) is deprecated and removed out of php7.

Comment: @k0pernikus yeah but that not important for my codes now i need to fix it once xml array codes ty.

Comment: @ any idea ? i try everything but dont resolve it.